# Как вывести значение double с 1 цифрой после запятой?

Tags: ios, objective-c, double

Этот код выводит 2 цифры после запятой. Пример: 2007.64

```
double ohm = (2500.0 / rst) - 2500.0;
label2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", ohm];
```

Как вывести значение 2007.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", ohm]
```